# are there any theme packs for material-ui (reactJS + material design)?

Tags: themes, material-ui

I specifically mean the reactJS & material-ui project:
http://www.material-ui.com/

searching on theme-forest etc. doesn't turn up anything.
there are themes that use other front-end material design packages

such as:

http://preview.themeforest.net/item/materio-material-design-mobile-app-landing-page/full_screen_preview/10910350
^ materializecss

or

http://www.strapui.com/product-category/react.js-themes/
^ react + bootstrap

Converting the JS components to a different library seems like a whole lot of work... same as building from scratch really.

Thanks for any suggestions or quick ways to get a designed layouted site up and running!

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/CreativeIT/material-dashboard-lite